# Android Studio noob - GUI for Gradle?

Tags: android-studio

I'm coming from an Eclipse, Visual Studio background and I'm trying to learn the basics of Android Studio. (2.1.1)

When I search the web looking for basic "how-to's" for Android Studio, I notice that lots of basic things like setting up API and SDK level build targets in Android Studio seem to be done by hand-editing *.gradle* files, which are written in their own scripting language.   I've never needed to do that in Eclipse or Visual Studio, even though I understand it's possible, and back in the old days people used to routinely edit "make" files for building C programs.

**My Question:**  Does Android Studio have a GUI for setting the things that go in *.gradle* files or does everything have to be done by hand-editing?   If the latter, does Android Studio have a *gradle*-aware source editor that can flag syntax errors, etc?

PS - is there a more active question/discussion for Android Studio questions than Stack Overflow?  I've posted a couple of prior Android Studio questions which have received no answers and very few views, much less than I used to get with Eclipse, even though Android Studio is now the "official" IDE for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Android Studio have a GUI for setting the things that go in .gradle files or does everything have to be done by hand-editing?

Some things can be configured via File > Project Structure from the Android Studio main menu. However, Gradle is based on the Groovy scripting language, and so there are lots of things that you cannot do in the Project Structure dialog.

> If the latter, does Android Studio have a gradle-aware source editor that can flag syntax errors, etc?

Yes.